# How to find length of array

Tags: c

I made a histogram and try to find the length of a histogram.
But the length of the histogram give me the wrong output. Here is my code first.

```
int *n = calloc(l,sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
    }
int *hist = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i<l; i++){
        hist[n[i]]++;
        hist = realloc(hist, sizeof(int));
    }

//length of histogram array
int histlen = sizeof(hist)/sizeof(hist[0]);

printf("legnth : %d\n", histlen);
```

So

```
input: 3 3 3 2 2 1
```

the output should be

```
length:3
```

But my code give me

```
length:2
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `hist[n[i]]++` is doing?

Comment: `hist` is not an array, it's a pointer. If the expression `e` has type `T`, `sizeof(e)` is equivalent to `sizeof(T)`. That is, you have `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`.

Comment: If all you have is a pointer, it (usually) points to the first element of the array, and that's really all the information you have. There's no way to get the length of the allocated memory from that single pointer, you need to keep track of it yourself in another variable.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: Long before you do `hist[3]++;`, you have to make sure there *is* a `hist[3]`.

Comment: The length of the histogram is easily known, in case the code is corrected from `int *hist = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));` to `int *hist = (int*) malloc(sizeofhistogram * sizeof(int));`. You have to know the length of any allocation you ask for anyway. And it obviously is the size of the data value range, which in turn you should already know, at least its theoretical maximum.

Comment: The line `hist = realloc(hist, sizeof(int));` does nothing. The `realloc` function takes a pointer, and a *new* size. In your code, the new size is the same as the old size, so `realloc` will just return the old pointer.

Comment: *"The output should be 3"* Why? Are you trying to calculate the frequencies of  each value in the inputted array and find the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a `struct array` which will hold the length and the pointer to an array.

```
struct array {
    int length;
    int* values;
}
```

Then in your code you can get the length with `arr.length` and the pointer with `arr.values`.